# Ubuntu 14.04 Server operated as a WIFI-LAN-Router drops packets between LAN and WIFI

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, network-bridge, router

**I would like beeing able to exchange packets between WIFI and LAN.**

My Ubuntu 14.04 Server operated as a lan-wifi-router has two physical Ethernet Ports (**p4p1** and **p5p1**) as well as a WIFI Module (**wlan0**). The p4p1 interface is my connection to the internet and gets its adress via DHCP from my provider.

wlan0 and p5p1 are connected to a bridge **br0** which uses the static adress **192.168.3.1**. Both indiviual interfaces have no adress. dnsmaq assignes each device at br0 to an ip adress. I used [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router) guide to set up my router.

I'm able to reach the internet from both LAN and WIFI. It is also possible to ping each device from the servers console. But i am not able to connect from one part of the network to another. Hence, my WIFI printer can only be operated by the server and not by the clients.

I can confirm that packets are sent and reach the bridge br0, but they fail to reach the interface after the bridge. This has been tested with wireshark.

**Configuration:**

/etc/networking/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto p4p1
iface p4p1 inet dhcp

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 192.168.3.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.3.255
    bridge_ports p5p1 wlan0
```

route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         XXX.XXX.XXX.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 p4p1
XXX.XXX.XXX.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 p4p1
192.168.3.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
```

Is there any obvious fault? Maybe in the routing table?

**Edit 1:** 
I already had this line in /etc/sysctl.conf uncommented.

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Hence, the solution from [darent](https://askubuntu.com/a/524357/327135) did not work.

**Edit 2:**
Has anyone an idea why the third line of the routing table has the gateway 0.0.0.0? May this be the source of the problem? Shouldn't this be 192.168.3.1?

**Edit 3:** I simplified my /etc/networking/interfaces file.

**Edit 4:** As i'm still trying to handle this problem, here is my

iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             LOG level warning

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found die source of the problem. My iptables FORWARD chain had the policy "**DROP**" adopted.

I needed a redesign of my iptables rules. But I basically did a

```
iptables --policy FORWARD ACCEPT
```

and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Is the server configured to forward the packages it receives? Try this:

```
sudo sysctl net/ipv4/ip_forward=1
```

Comment: Yes i tried it, but the problem still occours. I also edited my initial question.